# magento2 before add to cart open popup how to?

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart, popup, ajaxaddtocart

```
submitForm: function (form) {
            //this.ajaxSubmit(form);
            var popup = $('<div class="add-to-cart-modal-popup"/>').html($('.page-title span').text() + '<span> has been added to cart.</span>').modal({
                modalClass: 'add-to-cart-popup',
                title: $.mage.__("Popup Title"),
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Continue Shopping',
                        click: function () {
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Add To Cart',
                        click: function () {
                            this.ajaxSubmit(form);
                            
                            //return false;
                            //window.location = window.checkout.checkoutUrl
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            popup.modal('openModal');
        },
```

Comment: i have try above way but error show like Uncaught TypeError: this.ajaxSubmit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
submitForm: function (form) {
        //this.ajaxSubmit(form);
        var self = this;
        var popup = $('<div class="add-to-cart-modal-popup"/>').html($('.page-title span').text() + '<span> has been added to cart.</span>').modal({
            modalClass: 'add-to-cart-popup',
            title: $.mage.__("Popup Title"),
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Continue Shopping',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Add To Cart',
                    click: function () {
                        self.ajaxSubmit(form);
                        
                        //return false;
                        //window.location = window.checkout.checkoutUrl
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        popup.modal('openModal');
    },
```

Comment: Thanks now working fine

Answer (score 0):

customfun: function (form) {
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#flea-and-word').valid()) {
self.ajaxSubmit(form);

```
            }else{
                $(".error-header-message").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: self.ajaxSubmit is not a function issue me